# Subsequence definition question.

Tags: real-analysis

If $(p_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $(q_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ are sequences for each $k \in \mathbb{N}$, $q_k = p_{n_k}$ then $(q_k)$ is a subsequence of $(p_n)$.

I have trouble understanding this, especially the notation $p_{n_k}$.

Note: $k$ is a subscript of $n$.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

$n_k$ is a sequence of natural numbers, and $p_{n_k}$ is the subsequence of $p_k$ only at the terms $n_k$.  Perhaps an example would be illustrative:

Let's say $n_k = 2k$ and $p_k = (-1)^{k}$.  As you know, $p_k$ does not converge, but it does have a convergent subsequence $q_k = p_{n_k} = (-1)^{2k} = 1$.